# Recent posts on homepage: different thumbnail based on logged in status and post category

Tags: post-thumbnails, user-roles, get-posts, recent-posts

This works well on `archive.php`, but not working on the homepage. For some reason, the first statement doesn't get applied: if a post is in Members category and user is not logged in, it's supposed to show a default placeholder image, but instead it's still showing the actual post thumbnail.

```php
<?php if (!is_user_logged_in() && in_category('members')) { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/default-login.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
    </a>
                                
<?php } 
    else if (is_user_logged_in() || !in_category('members')) { ?>                 

        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_item['ID']) ?>">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_item['ID'], 'news-thumb'); ?>
        </a>
                                    
    <?php } else { ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/default.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
            </a>

    <?php } ?>
```

I'm using:

```php
<?php
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => 6, // Number of recent posts to display
    'post_status' => 'publish' // Show only the published posts
));

foreach( $recent_posts as $post_item ) : ?>
```

Final version so far:

```
<?php
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 6,        // Number of recent posts to display
    'post_status' => 'publish' // Show only the published posts
    ), OBJECT );  // 1. Set the second parameter to OBJECT.
                        
    global $post; // 2. Access the global $post variable.
        foreach ( $recent_posts as $post ) : // 3. Rename $post_item to $post
        setup_postdata( $post );         // 4. Set up global post data. ?>
                            
<div>
<?php if (!is_user_logged_in() && in_category('members')) { ?>
                            
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/default-login.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
    </a>
                                
<?php } 
    else if (is_user_logged_in() || !in_category('members')) { ?>                 
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_item['ID']) ?>">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_item['ID'], 'news-thumb'); ?>
        </a>
                                    
<?php } else { ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/default.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
         </a>
<?php } ?>
                                    
    <a rel="bookmark" href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_item['ID']) ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
    <h6><?php the_title(); ?></h6>
    </a>
    <div><time datetime="<?php echo get_the_date('c'); ?>">
        <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></time>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php
            $content = get_the_content();
            $content = preg_replace("~(?:\[/?)[^/\]]+/?\]~s", '', $content);  # strip shortcodes, keep shortcode content

            $trimmed_content = wp_trim_words( $content, 14, '... <br /><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">Continue reading &gt;</a>' );            
        echo $trimmed_content;
            ?>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In what template you put the code? In a template part that's loaded in the loop? Try adding `var_dump( get_post(), in_category( 'members' ), is_user_logged_in() );` somewhere and see if the data are correct for the current post and user.

Comment: Oops, it's outside the loop on the homepage.

Comment: I'm using 
`<?php 
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
              'numberposts' => 6, // Number of recent posts to display
              'post_status' => 'publish' // Show only the published posts
          ));
          foreach( $recent_posts as $post_item ) : ?>`

Comment: I've added that to the question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `the_` functions (e.g. `the_permalink()` and `the_title()`) and including `in_category()` (*without* specifying the second parameter) outside of The Loop (the standard one which calls `the_post()`), you should access the global `$post` variable and call [`setup_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/setup_postdata/) to set up global post data and after your `foreach` ends, call [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/) to restore the `$post` back to the current post in the main query.

You also must rename the `$post_item` variable to `$post` and I'd also use `OBJECT` as the second parameter value for [`wp_get_recent_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_recent_posts/), although you could actually do `setup_postdata( (object) $post )`.

### Working Example

```php
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 6,        // Number of recent posts to display
    'post_status' => 'publish' // Show only the published posts
), OBJECT );  // 1. Set the second parameter to OBJECT.

global $post; // 2. Access the global $post variable.
foreach ( $recent_posts as $post ) : // 3. Rename $post_item to $post
    setup_postdata( $post );         // 4. Set up global post data.

    // ... your code here ..
    echo ( in_category( 'members' ) ? 'In' : '<b>Not</b> in' ) . ' Members category';
    the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>' );
endforeach;

wp_reset_postdata(); // 5. Restore the $post variable.
```

Remember, you need to change the `$post_item` in your code to `$post` *and* use the "arrow" to access the post data, e.g. `$post->ID` and not `$post['ID']`! :)

Comment: Thank you, works great! I will look up the use of OBJECT, haven't really come across it much.

Comment: It's still working with `$post_item['ID']`. Is it not supposed to?

Comment: Are you sure? If you renamed it to `$post`, then `$post_item` would be undefined.. so it wouldn't work.

Comment: But if you meant `$post_item['ID']` versus `$post_item->ID`, then yes, the former would work if you used the default value for the second parameter for `wp_get_recent_posts()` which is `ARRAY_A`.. :)

Comment: I've revised my original with the full snippet. It works great, but can you please comment on what's not efficient there, if anything? Thank you!

Comment: Your code is good, except the `$post_item` is no longer defined (because you've renamed it to `$post` and it is now an *object*), so you should've used `$post->ID` and not `$post_item['ID']`, but then, I would change the `echo get_permalink( ... )` to `the_permalink()`, and the `echo get_the_post_thumbnail( ... )` to `the_post_thumbnail( 'news-thumb' )`. Also, when used in an HTML attribute, you should use `the_title_attribute()` and not `the_title()` =)